# How to write a regexp replace that keeps part of my string?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 and working on some code refactoring.  I have a lot of code fragments (hundreds) that look like this:

```
IF g_debug = 1 THEN
  display_log('GET_CHANGE_REASON_CODE: Entry');
END IF ;
```

What I would like to do is replace everything but keep the section in parentheses (I am refactoring this logic into its own function), so that it looks like this:

```
debug('GET_CHANGE_REASON_CODE: Entry');
```

Note that I am also wanting to get rid of the 2 spaces in front of the original "display_log" call.

The regexp search that I have derived so far matches everything up through `display_log`, but I am having trouble ignoring the section in parentheses and going on to match the `END IF` line.

I am also unsure of how to write the replace regexp string.  Here is what I have so far:

```
IF g_debug = 1 THEN(?s)(.*?)display_log(?s)(.*?)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `(?s)IF\s+g_debug\s*=\s*1\s+THEN\s*display_log(\(.*?)^END IF\s*;` and replace with `debug$1`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/9RqQB6/1).

Comment: Wow thanks.  I forgot to mention that sometimes I might have several lines of display_log('some text') within the IF statement.  How would I change each of those lines to say debug('some text')?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this - `display_log\((.*?)\)\;`, replace with `debug($1);`. That will remove the `IF...THEN` requirement from your code, which you probably don't need.